# Is it possible to run ASP.NET MVC 3 apps on Mono?

Tags: mono

I need to run some MVC 3 app on Linux running server, and it seems the only option is Mono? the site only talks about the web services but I wish to know running the whole mvc 3 app is also possible? thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5019191/is-it-possible-to-get-an-asp-net-mvc-3-project-working-under-mono-2-10

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends what you mean by the "whole mvc 3 app". The ASP.Net MVC3 stack has been implemented in Mono but check [here](http://www.mono-project.com/Compatibility) and [here](http://www.mono-project.com/Release_Notes_Mono_2.10#ASP.NET_MVC3_Support) for further details.