# Does Cloud 9 support .Net for build or deploy or debug?

Tags: c#-4.0, cloud9-ide

I really want to know is Cloud 9(https://c9.io/) support .Net(C#)?
My target is using .Net 4.0 + MVC 3.0 for my project.

There are "Run With" future for "New Runner", is that can make Cloud 9 support .Net?

Comment: I am not certain but it seems that there is no trace of NET in their docs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Cloud9 workspaces come preinstalled with [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/), so [in theory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14681855/is-it-possible-to-run-asp-net-mvc-3-apps-on-mono) you could compile and run any C#/.NET code. You can write [custom runners](https://docs.c9.io/custom_runners.html) and builders that use Mono to compile your code. So, there is not a lot of support for it out of the box, but if you're willing to put in some effort you may be able to get it working.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, and I will try the custom runners.

Answer (score 24):

Yes, it does.

[image]

### INSTALL PROCEDURE

Add the Mono Project GPG signing key and the package repository

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 3FA7E0328081BFF6A14DA29AA6A19B38D3D831EF
echo "deb http://download.mono-project.com/repo/debian wheezy main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mono-xamarin.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get update --fix-missing
```

Then install Mono as described

```
sudo apt-get install mono-complete
sudo apt-get install mono-devel
sudo apt-get install referenceassemblies-pcl
```

### HOW COMPILE CONSOLE APPLICATION

To compile, use mcs:

```
mcs filename.cs
```

The compiler will create filename.exe, which you can run using:

```
mono filename.exe
```

### ADDITIONAL RESOURCES

- Visit [mono-project.com/docs/getting-started/install/linux/](http://mono-project.com/docs/getting-started/install/linux/) for
  support on the install procedure
- Visit [mono-project.com/docs/getting-started/mono-basics/](http://mono-project.com/docs/getting-started/mono-basics/) to
  learn more about using mono basics
- Visit mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/compatibility/ for latest
  version of .NET support

Comment: Thanks @Boo provide the answer, I will kept it in mine.

Comment: For those that just wanna CTRL+C and CTRL+V...

`sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 3FA7E0328081BFF6A14DA29AA6A19B38D3D831EF && \
echo "deb http://download.mono-project.com/repo/debian wheezy main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mono-xamarin.list   && \
  sudo apt-get update && \
  sudo apt-get update --fix-missing && \
  sudo apt-get install mono-complete && \
  sudo apt-get install mono-devel && \
  sudo apt-get install referenceassemblies-pcl `

Answer (score 2):

It also supports .net core, where according to this [Douglas](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/net-core-cloud-9-ide-douglas-starnes), you can do it via these steps:

1. Follow [instructions](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#ubuntu) for installing .net core on Linux (ubuntu)
2. Find a sample on git [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Home)
3. Run it.

Answer (score 1):

It does work, you can add a custom runner like in the following example to build .csproj and .sln files:

```
{
    "cmd" : ["/usr/lib/mono/4.0/xbuild.exe", "$file","/p:Configuration=Release /p:DebugSymbols=false /p:PreBuildEvent=;PostBuildEvent="],
    "info" : "Started $project_path$file_name",
    "env" : {},
    "selector" : "source.csproj"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the following to create a new C# runner:

```
{
  "script": [ 
    "mcs $file_name",
    "mono $file_base_name.exe"
  ],
  "info": "Compiling $file_name and running $file_base_name.exe",
  "selector": "source.cs"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

https://codenvy.io

It supports .NET Core on Linux (docker based) environment on the cloud.